# Mysql select query with count

Tags: mysql, select

I need to create a select query with count from another table.

I have two tables like `category` and `candidates`. Every candidate belong to one category.

Here I want to select all categories from category table along with how many candidates available for each category.

like this: `category_name(23)`

This is how I tried it. but it doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT c.category_id
         , c.name
         , COUNT(cn.job_category) AS cvs  
FROM job_category c  
LEFT JOIN candidates cn ON cn.job_category = c.category_id
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `group by` clause.

```
SELECT c.category_id
         , c.name
         , COUNT(cn.job_category) AS cvs  
FROM job_category c  
    LEFT JOIN candidates cn ON cn.job_category = c.category_id
GROUP BY c.category_id
         , c.name
ORDER BY c.name ASC
```

Note: Without `group by`, `mysql` will just return an arbitrary category. It allows this behavior while most other database systems would result in an error when you don't include non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause.